# How can i Set decimal value in SQL (something like 10.12345678)

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Can't store decimal value in SQL.
Want to store like decimal(2,8)

Like 32.12345678

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(2,8)")]
        [Display(Name = "Latitude")]
        public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
```

In NuGet Consol

```
Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [DredgingDatas] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [DredgerId] int NOT NULL,
    [DredgingTime] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [Density] decimal NOT NULL,
    [Velocity] decimal NOT NULL,
    [Production] decimal NOT NULL,
    [Latitude] decimal(2, 8) NOT NULL,
    [Longitude] decimal(2, 8) NOT NULL,
    [Tide] decimal NOT NULL,
    [DredgeHead] float NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_DredgingDatas] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_DredgingDatas_Dredgers_DredgerId] FOREIGN KEY ([DredgerId]) REFERENCES [Dredgers] ([DredgerId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

The scale (8) for column 'Latitude' must be within the range 0 to 2.
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear - the values are in the wrong order. Use `(8,2)`. Two digits don't make sense for coordinates though and you probably want `(10,8)`

Comment: On the other hand you may want to use SQL Server's spatial geometry or geography types if you want to perform spatial searches

Comment: The number before the comma in a `decimal(p,s)` specification is the total number of digits in the number, so to store your sample number you need to use `decimal(10,8)`

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, it worked out.
But for this time I don't need spatial database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is a slight misunderstanding of the decimal data type. The first part of the declaration is the total length of the data field, the second is the amount of those that are decimals.

For example: `decimal(5,3)` shows a precision of 5 total digits, 3 of those are decimal places (12.345).

I think you are looking for the data type `decimal(10,8)` which would give you 10 total digits, with 8 of those coming *after* the decimal place

Here's a link to the documentation that explains how the precision works;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks for your kind help Mr. Bennar, it worked out.